# How to monitor Java process using SNMP

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmp-trap

I need to monitor a Java process using SNMP i.e if the Java process is down it should send a Trap . Need help in how to use net-snmp to monitor the java process

My queries are for net-snmp:

Do I have to create a MIB for my Java process?
How does the SNMP agent receive the status? Does it runs some script to collect the status report? Where should the script be configured?
If I have the MIB file will it be sufficient to use with the SNMP agent or I have to write some scripts also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java can give you SNMP information by itself. See [SNMP Monitoring and Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/snmp.html).

You need to activate it using the "*com.sun.management.snmp.port*" system propertie and an *ACL file*.

The problem is that it will not send traps if it crashes, you can *only* get "live/running" information.

To monitor the java process itself (is it live or dead, send a trap when crashing) you have to use an external tool such as [Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) configured with the `proc` directive and "*DisMan Event MIB*". See [man pages](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/man/snmpd.conf.html) for more information.